# Rear left passenger side reverse bulb keeps blowing

Tags: electrical, subaru, lights, bulbs, reverse-lights

I've been having an ongoing problem with my 2007 Subaru outback whereby my left side reverse light bulb keeps blowing.

I've replaced the bulb about 3 times now and it blows every time. It works when I first replace it, I test it out for about 10 or so minutes and it all seems fine, then a day or two later its blown again.

I also tried replacing the actual connector that the bulb goes in to, but that also only lasted for a day or two.

So, I'm totally stumped as to what could be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: sound like a short or a bad ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later model Subarus apparently have a problem with bulbs.  There is at least one lawsuit going on about front headlights.  Some people complaining they have to replace one or both every 3-6 months.
The theory I've heard is that noise in the system causes spikes in the voltage.
https://www.torquenews.com/1084/subaru-covering-outback-lighting-failures

Bottom line, Verify ground circuit is good.  Verify no other lighting issues.  Make sure the bulb is dry (no rain getting in).  I would use a dielectric grease on the socket/bulb.  If you are still having the issue, consider monitoring the signal to the bulb.  I have an AC/DC meter that can measure both at the same time.  It would be interesting to see if the AC spikes.  It would also be curious why other bulbs aren't failing.

Also see: https://allwheeldriveauto.com/subaru-head-light-bulb-life-explained/